# Application Project has not been registered

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run my react native app on my device . 
So I am running `react-native start`
everything looks fine. 
[image]

and when running `react-native run-android` I get this error 
[image]

otherwise, I get this error in my device

[image]

Comment: check your index.andorid.js. check the line AppRegistry.registerComponent .check if u have properly registered the class. Also make sure u are on the correct project folder

Comment: i put class  'proj  extends Component ' and  for the app registery 'AppRegistry.registerComponent('proj', () => proj)' . ps : my prject's name is proj

Comment: Please post the code index.andorid.js

Comment: `import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text,
  View
}
from 'react-native'
  class  proj  extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text >
          Welcome to PutainDeBiere!
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent('proj', () => proj)`

Comment: use the code below

Answer (score 10):

My issue was the name I gave the project differed from the name that was being registered in AppRegistry

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('proj', () => proj)
```

`proj` needs to be the same as the name of the project in the gradle and config files.

Comment: thanks! this worked for me. i just had to change the `'proj'` part to the name of my Xcode Project

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the class. Use the code below

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react' 
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native'
export default class proj extends Component {
 render() { 
return ( 
<View style={styles.container}> <Text > Welcome to PutainDeBiere! </Text> </View> ) 
} 
}
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('proj', () => proj)
```

Comment: check your index.ios.js the following line should be same  in both if not use the one in ios file.. the first parameter is the name of the project .. it should be correct.  AppRegistry.registerComponent('proj', () => proj) .. if everything fails shutdown everything and restart

Comment: i have the same code in  index.ios.js  as in index.android.js. I get  the same error

Comment: ps : i have problemwhen running npm installin the project

Comment: @SihemHcine try sudo rm -rf node_modules then npm install

Answer (score 0):

Delete / uninstall first the APP installed and then do a clean install of it and see if it works.

Comment: did you move the files to another folder or something? it can cause problems if the xcode files and others doesn't have the same name has the project

Comment: try on the terminal: `lsof -i :8081` and use the PID of the several things that appear on the terminal,  `kill -9 PID`, when there's nothing try to run the APP again

Comment: i try lsof -i :8081 , nothing is appeared but i get the same error :(

Comment: nothing appears? i should appear at least 1 , do react-native start on one terminal and react-native start on another, and then try the lsof command to see if it shows something, don't ever close the react native start terminal

Comment: the same thing ,i wonder if the the problem is from node version , it s 4.x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148476/discussion-between-sihem-hcine-and-brunaine).